# Ansible mysql8 root passwords and native users

Tags: ansible, mysql-8.0

I am new to ansible and having spent a long time searching I feel as though I am missing something which should be obvious.

**Problem**

After installing MySql8 using ansible on a Ubuntu 20.04  server I can't do anything else MySql related because the password for the MySql "root" user is set to something random and saved into the error logs. The only solution I have found to this is to retrieve the password and change it. However, this would only work once. Running the same playbook again later will cause an error since the password will already have been changed.

I have a similar issue when it comes to creating a user identified by a MySQL native password. I have found solutions which do this by first creating a user, then using a shell command to convert the user to be identified by a native password. But I don't really want that to happen every time the playbook is run. What I want is the user to be created only if it doesn't exist already.

If I were doing this manually, I would either log into MySql using
`sudo mysql`
or else set the root password using the mysql_secure_installation script.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to set the root MySQL account password from ansible
   without knowing the current password by using the sudo password like
   above?
2. Is it possible to create a user identified by a native password
   without using shell commands so that the user only gets created if
   it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with mysql8.0 
My solution at the time was below steps

1. Get temp password for root from 
   `sudo grep "temporary password" /var/log/mysqld.log|cut -d ' ' -f 11`
2. Update root password (Possibly use mysql_user module) 
   `"sudo mysqladmin -u root password '{{ new_mysql_root_password }}' -p'{{ password_from_1 }}'"`

I did this with 2 sudo commands using shell module but the ideal way would be i think \
do 1 using shell module
do a connection check on mysql using 1 and register it in a variable root_check
do 2 only `when` root_check does not throw error.

In my case, I ignored the error if it occurs at 2 if the password is changed the first time.

I am sure there is a better solution.